# Jquery syntax and variables

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, css, fadeout

I'm trying to make a FadeOut effect after clicking a link. But my syntax seems to be wrong. When i click, it fadeout, and go to a **"~~nothing~~.html"** page, it just dont get the value to compose the variable.
the id boo is attached to the  tag (**body id="boo"**) and in the css stylesheet the id **#boo** is set to **display:none;**
I'm using jquery-1.7.2.min

```
<script type="text/javascript">
    $(document).ready(function(){
        $('#go').click(function(e) { //When something with the id 'go' is clicked, 
            e.preventDefault(); //Prevent default action (?)
            var url = $('#go').val() + ".html"; //set url as "Clicked 'go' value + .html" (374.html"
            $('#boo').fadeOut(600, function() { window.location.href = url; }); //fadeOut what is with the 'boo' id (body), and load the created address as a new page (?)
        });
    });
</script>
<a id="go" value="374" href="#">Go to page 374</a>
```

the 374.html page is in the same folder. If possible, please explain what have i done wrong, and make it step by step. I'm new to jquery.

Thank you!

Answer (score 3, accepted):

the `.val()` method only applies to fields, just putting a `value` attribute on any element will *not* be read with the `val()` method.

Instead use `.attr('value')`.

Or, its better practice to use `data-*` attributes and use the `data()` method:

```
<script type="text/javascript">
    $(document).ready(function(){
        $('#go').click(function(e) { //When something with the id 'go' is clicked, 
            e.preventDefault(); //Prevent default action (?)
            var url = $('#go').data('value') + ".html"; //set url as "Clicked 'go' value + .html" (374.html"
            $('#boo').fadeOut(600, function() { window.location.href = url; }); //fadeOut what is with the 'boo' id (body), and load the created address as a new page (?)
        });
    });
</script>
<a id="go" data-value="374" href="#">Go to page 374</a>
```

Comment: It works, but if i use more than one <a> link, it would /always/ get the first one's id

Comment: @ghaschel - but you cant have more than one element with the id `go`? Also, dont re-use the selector `#go` inside the clich event, use `$(this)` to get the actual clicked link!

Comment: Srry, that was embarrassing. Solved my problem using $(this) and .go instead of #go

Answer (score 1):

Try:

```
var url = $('#go').attr("value") + ".html";
```

instead of

```
var url = $('#go').val() + ".html";
```

From the jQuery [docs](http://api.jquery.com/val/) -

> The .val() method is primarily used to get the values of form elements
>   such as input, select and textarea. In the case of  elements, the .val() method returns an array
>   containing each selected option; if no option is selected, it returns
>   null.

There's an example here - http://jsfiddle.net/A8ArH/

Comment: the .val() works with
    <select id="go">
        <option value="374">Goto page 374</option>
    </select>
that's why i thought it would work

Comment: and a button, with the id "make", and in the first "go" in the js code, a "make" id instead. If i'm not wrong

Comment: I've added some text from the jQuery docs, it suggests that the `val()` function is designed to work with input elements. This would back up the experiences you've had.

Answer (score 1):

The `val()` function won't give you that value from an anchor tag, use `attr("value")` to get the valuue of the a tag

```
$(document).ready(function(){
    $('#go').click(function(e) { 
        e.preventDefault(); 
        var url = $('#go').attr("value") + ".html"; 
        alert(url)
        $('#boo').fadeOut(600, function() {
                 window.location.href = url; 
        });
    });
});​
```

Alternatively, you can use HTML 5 `data` attribute to store such kind of value

```
<a id="go" data-someValue="374" href="#">Go to page 374</a>
```

And you can access it in javascript like

```
var someVal=$("#go").data("someValue");
```

sample http://jsfiddle.net/LyPZB/1/

Answer (score 1):

The **a** tag doesn't support the attribute *value*, you should do like this:

set the anchor like this

```
<a id="go" data-page="374" href="#">...
```

(data-xxx are custom attributes)

and get its value with

```
$('#go').data('page')
```

In this way it will work and you will respect the HTML standard (since the anchor shouldn't have the value attribute)